# How to get the trios repeated by rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

How may I get a column with the repeated values by rows? If I have the following dataset:

```
    DOC      A                B                C               D
 1 Doc1    apple            berry            coconut          pear 
 2 Doc2    apple            banana           berry            prune
 3 Doc3    apple            banana           berry            coconut
 4 Doc4    banana           berry            pear             prune
```

The desired subset output would be:

```
  DOC           Trio                     A             B           C           D

1 Doc1     apple, berry, coconut      apple         berry        coconut     pear
2 Doc3     apple, berry, coconut      apple         banana       berry       coconut

3 Doc2     apple, banana, berry       apple         banana       berry       prune
4 Doc3     apple, banana, berry       apple         banana       berry       coconut

5 Doc2     banana, berry, prune       apple         banana       berry       prune
6 Doc4     banana, berry, prune       banana        berry        pear        prune
```

The idea is to get all the possibles trios within the same row that repeat in other rows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cant follow the logic to get the deesired output, can you explain the rules a bit mroe clearly?

Comment: So, the idea is to be able to identify in each doc, three keywords that are repeated in another doc, and after doing it, paste them (the keywords being repeated) together to those docs.

Answer (score 1):

This can do the trick.

```
text="
Doc     A               B            C            D
Doc1    apple            berry            coconut          pear 
Doc2    apple            banana           berry            prune
Doc3    apple            banana           berry            coconut
Doc4    banana           berry            pear             prune"
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df=read.table(text=text, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1=data.frame(DOC=c(), Trio=c(), A=c(), B=c(), C=c(), D=c())
for (i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)) {
  for (j in (i+1):nrow(df)) {
    com1=combn(df[i,2:5], 3)
    com2=combn(df[j,2:5], 3)
    for (k in 1:ncol(com1)) {
      for (h in 1:ncol(com2)) {
        if (setequal(com1[,k], com2[,h])) {
          trio=str_c(com1[1,k], ", ", com1[2,k], ", ", com1[3,k])
          df2=mutate(df[i,], Trio=trio)
          df3=mutate(df[j,], Trio=trio)
          df1=bind_rows(df1, df2, df3)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
df1=relocate(df1, Trio, .after=Doc)

   Doc                  Trio      A      B       C       D
1 Doc1 apple, berry, coconut  apple  berry coconut    pear
2 Doc3 apple, berry, coconut  apple banana   berry coconut
3 Doc2  apple, banana, berry  apple banana   berry   prune
4 Doc3  apple, banana, berry  apple banana   berry coconut
5 Doc2  banana, berry, prune  apple banana   berry   prune
6 Doc4  banana, berry, prune banana  berry    pear   prune
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is alternative base R approach. You can determine all combinations of "DOC" to begin with. Then, in a loop compare each combination of "DOC" with `intersect` to see if there are 3 elements in common. If so, store those rows in a list and include the trio of common elements identified. Further processing may be needed if you want to avoid duplicate rows (and if that is a consideration).

```
combos <- combn(df$DOC, 2)
idx <- 1
lst <- list()
for (i in 1:ncol(combos)) {
  r1 <- df[df$DOC == combos[1, i], ]
  r2 <- df[df$DOC == combos[2, i], ]
  j <- intersect(unlist(r1)[-1], unlist(r2)[-1])
  if (length(j) == 3) {
    lst[[idx]] <- data.frame(rbind(r1, r2), trio = toString(j))
    idx <- idx + 1
  }
}
do.call(rbind, lst)
```

**Output**

```
    DOC      A      B       C       D                  trio
1  Doc1  apple  berry coconut    pear apple, berry, coconut
3  Doc3  apple banana   berry coconut apple, berry, coconut
2  Doc2  apple banana   berry   prune  apple, banana, berry
31 Doc3  apple banana   berry coconut  apple, banana, berry
21 Doc2  apple banana   berry   prune  banana, berry, prune
4  Doc4 banana  berry    pear   prune  banana, berry, prune
```